# How do I activate a widget using Tkinter inside of a match operation of another class?

Tags: python, class, tkinter, widget, match

So basically I have this program that will parse the contents of a file and ask for input from the user when it comes across a command. It was a console-only program, and I'm trying to convert it into a GUI.
The issue is, I need the GUI to prompt the user to enter a value only when the command is triggered in the program, and I think I have the code laid out and it's just not showing up on the screen. I know the program can parse through it and trigger an input to the console, so it's parsing it correctly. I think it's just the way I'm trying to activate the widgets. It gets up to the point where it prints the contents of the file to the screen, and then it just does nothing after that. Let me know if you need the rest of the files.

```py
class Frame(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("UVSim")

        self.main = Main(self)

        self.mainloop()


class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.input = None
        self.prog = Memory()
        self.executor()

    def executor(self):
        operation = ''

        while self.prog.pointer <= 99 and operation != '43':
            if len(self.prog.registers[self.prog.pointer]) == 5:
                operation = self.prog.registers[self.prog.pointer][1:3]
                mem = int(self.prog.registers[self.prog.pointer][3:])

            elif len(self.prog.registers[self.prog.pointer]) == 4:
                operation = self.prog.registers[self.prog.pointer][0:2]
                mem = int(self.prog.registers[self.prog.pointer][2:])

            if operation == '10':  # Check if the operation is '10'# this used to be inside of the match operation
                self.input = UserInput(self)  # this is where the widget should be created
                self.input.read_entry()
                word_entry = self.input.get_entry()
                self.prog.read(mem, word_entry)

            match operation:
                # i/o operations:
                # READ

                case '11':
                    self.prog.write(mem)
                # load/store operations:
                # LOAD
                case '20':
                    self.prog.load(mem)
        

class UserInput (tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.entry = None
        self.display_label = None
        self.read_entry()

    def read_entry(self):
        enter = tk.Label(text="Please enter an input")
        enter.pack()

        self.entry = tk.Entry()
        self.entry.pack()

        submit_button = tk.Button(text="Submit", command=self.print_entry)
        submit_button.pack()

        self.display_label = tk.Label(text="")
        self.display_label.pack()
        
    def print_entry(self):
        entry_value = self.get_entry()
        self.display_label.config(text=f"Entered value: {entry_value}")
    
    def get_entry(self):
        return self.entry.get()


Frame()
```

I've tried creating classes, putting the '10' outside of the match operation block and into an if statement, packing the widgets in a separate function inside of UserInput, creating the widget directly inside the operation rather in a separate class, they all have the same result of nothing happening.

Comment: It is better to provide a [mre] as currently `Memory` is undefined.

Comment: Also avoid using `while` loop in a GUI application because it will block tkinter `mainloop()` from processing pending events and updates.